# Shape not stopping at the down boundary

Tags: java, swing, graphics, mouseevent, paint

I have a circle that I'm dragging around the screen. When it hits the left boundary, it stops. When it hits the right boundary, it stops. When it hit the top boundary it stops. But when it hits the bottom boundary, for some reason, it just keeps on going. Please help.

This is my MouseEvents class:

```
public class MouseEvents {

int x1;
int x2;
int y1;
int y2;
int dBMPPAFX;// difference-between-mouse-pointer-position-and-first-x-position
int dBMPPAFY;// difference-between-mouse-pointer-position-and-first-y-position
int width;
int height;
static boolean inside_;
static String whichBound = "";
static String text = "";

MouseEvents(int x1, int y1, int width, int height) {

    this.x1 = x1;
    this.y1 = y1;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.x2 = x1 + width;
    this.y2 = y1 + height;

}

static String hitBound(MouseEvents e, int width, int height) {
    whichBound = "";

    if (e.x1 <= 0) {
        whichBound = "left";
        e.x1 = 0;
        e.x2 = e.x1 + e.width;

    }
    if (e.x2 >= width) {
        whichBound = "right";
        e.x2 = width;
        e.x1 = e.x2 - e.width;

    }
    if (e.y1 <= 0) {
        whichBound = "up";
        e.y1 = 0;
        e.y2 = e.y1 + e.height;

    }
    if (e.y2 >= height) {
        whichBound = "down";
        e.y2 = height;
        e.y1 = e.y2 - e.height;

    }

    return whichBound;

}

static void showLocationOfXAndY(MouseEvents e, int x, int y) {

    e.text = Integer.toString(x) + "," + Integer.toString(y);

}

static boolean inside_(MouseEvents e, int x, int y) {
    if (x > e.x1 && x < e.x2 && y > e.y1 && y < e.y2) {
        e.dBMPPAFX = x - e.x1;
        e.dBMPPAFY = y - e.y1;
        e.x1 = x - e.dBMPPAFX;
        e.y1 = y - e.dBMPPAFY;
        e.x2 = e.x1 + e.width;
        e.y2 = e.y1 + e.height;

        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}

static void dragShape(MouseEvents e, int x, int y) {

    e.x1 = x - e.dBMPPAFX;
    e.y1 = y - e.dBMPPAFY;
    e.x2 = e.x1 + e.width;
    e.y2 = e.y1 + e.height;
}

}
```

This is my Panel class:

```
public class Panel extends JPanel {
int panelWidth;
int panelLength;

static Panel panel = new Panel(400, 400);
static JFrame frame = new JFrame("Monster");
static MouseEvents circle = new MouseEvents(250, 250, 50, 50);
static Events here = new Events();

@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(panelWidth, panelLength);
}

Panel(int width, int length) {
    panelWidth = width - 9;
    panelLength = length - 9;

}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    super.paintComponent(g);

    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    g.drawOval(circle.x1, circle.y1, circle.width, circle.height);
    g.drawString(circle.text, 100, 100);

}

public static void main(String args[]) {

    frame.add(panel);
    panel.addMouseListener(here);
    panel.addMouseMotionListener(here);

    Frame.showFrame(frame, false);

}

}
```

This is my Events class:

```
public class Events implements ActionListener, MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {
String s;

public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

    if (MouseEvents.inside_ && MouseEvents.hitBound(Panel.circle,400,400).equals("")) {
        dragShape(Panel.circle, e.getX(), e.getY());
        s = MouseEvents.hitBound(Panel.circle,400,400);
        System.out.println(s);

    }

    if (MouseEvents.inside_ && MouseEvents.hitBound(Panel.circle,400,400).equals("left")) {
        if(Panel.circle.x1>=0){
            dragShape(Panel.circle, e.getX(), e.getY());
        }

    }
    if (MouseEvents.inside_ && MouseEvents.hitBound(Panel.circle,400,400).equals("right")) {
        if(Panel.circle.x2<=400){
            System.out.println("What...."+Panel.circle.x2);
            dragShape(Panel.circle, e.getX(), e.getY());
            showLocationOfXAndY(Panel.circle, Panel.circle.x2, Panel.circle.y2);
        }
    }
    if (MouseEvents.inside_ && MouseEvents.hitBound(Panel.circle,400,400).equals("up")) {
        if(Panel.circle.y1>=0){
            dragShape(Panel.circle, e.getX(), e.getY());
        }
    }
    if (MouseEvents.inside_ && MouseEvents.hitBound(Panel.circle,400,400).equals("down")) {
        if(Panel.circle.y2<=400){
            System.out.println("What...."+Panel.circle.y2);

            dragShape(Panel.circle, e.getX(), e.getY());
            showLocationOfXAndY(Panel.circle, Panel.circle.x2, Panel.circle.y2);

        }
    }

    Panel.frame.repaint();



}

public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    showLocationOfXAndY(Panel.circle, Panel.circle.x2, Panel.circle.y2);

    Panel.frame.repaint();

}

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

}

public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

}

public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

}

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

    Panel.circle.inside_ = inside_(Panel.circle, e.getX(), e.getY());
    System.out.println(Panel.circle.inside_);
    System.out.println(hitBound(Panel.circle,400,400));

}

public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

    Panel.circle.inside_ = false;



    System.out.println("x1:"+Panel.circle.x1+"\ny1:"+Panel.circle.y1+"\nx2:"+Panel.circle.x2+"\ny2:"+Panel.circle.y2);

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

}

}
```

If anyone knows what I did wrong, please help. Thanks.

Comment: How come you don't call dragShape() as MouseEvents.dragShape()?

Comment: And what is Frame.showFrame? The correct way to show the frame would be to call frame.pack() and then frame.setVisible(true).

Comment: Its a method that does all that.

Comment: Because dragshape is a static method.

Comment: Sure enough. It was a bit confusing though, since you had cases of MouseEvents.hitBound() in the code, although hitBound() is static as well, which made me think you might not be using packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer, in the bottom of your mouseDragged() method, just before the repaint(), add a hitBound() like this:

```
...
MouseEvents.hitBound(Panel.circle,400,400);
Panel.frame.repaint();
...
```

So why does this happen? In each case in the mouseDragged method, you check if the hitBound equals one of the different edge cases. This works well, and the code enters the sections accordingly. When you are in one of the cases, you check if the circle is in a valid position to move, and if it is, you simply let the user move the circle again.

**This is the culprit.** For example: In the last case that doesn't work, you check the following:

```
MouseEvents.hitBound(Panel.circle,400,400).equals("down")
```

Which is true. Then you continue to check:

```
if(Panel.circle.y2 <= 400)
```

Which is also true, because the hitBound() call will set y2 to equal 400!

**Why does the other cases work then?** The other cases actually have the same problem, but you can't see it because you call hitBound() later in the next if cases. This will halt the position of the circle at the border, just as planned.

So as I mentioned before; a simple fix to this problem is to just add a call to hitBound() before repainting.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look at my code. It works! It'll take me some time to look through my codes a couple of times before I completely understands why it works, but thank you. It probabaly would take me days to figure out the problem. By the way, I'm curious. When you find yourself in a pinch, do you use a debugger? What is the best way to debug? How do you debug? Any tips or suggestions? Oh, and I just want to say thank you one more time. Most people wouldn't take the time to look through the codes like that because it's so long and complicated, and takes long time to undertand.

Comment: No problem! How I debug differs a bit between languages; if I'm coding C I might use a tool like gdb for example. But most of the time I only use prints to determine what's wrong. It might feel hopeless to know where to put the print statements and so on, but just look at the code and take it step by step. And a small tip is to read the code out loud to yourself, and compare it to what you want to happen, and that might reveal some errors in the logic of the code. Just keep at it and you'll be the king of debugging in the future!